# Meteor minimongo shows user logged in on client before server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

It appears that if a user is logged in to a Meteor application, then loses and regains their DDP connection, there is a short moment where the client believes that it is logged in before the server does.

For example, I have a container component that updates according to the result of `Meteor.loggingIn()`:

```js
const MainNavigationContainer = createContainer(props => {
    return {
        meteorReady: Meteor.loggingIn() === false
    }
}, MainNavigation);
```

In the `MainNavigation` component, I run a Meteor method which should return a result based on the user's `_id` (I have tried to remove irrelevant code):

```js
class MainNavigation extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setInitialRoute(nextProps);
    }
    setInitialRoute = (props) => {
        // Set up initial route
        if (props.meteorReady) {
            if (!Meteor.user()) {
                this.setState({initialRoute: routes[1]});
            } else {
                Meteor.call('/user/events/isActive', (e, eventId) => {
                    if (eventId) {
                        // Do some stuff
                    } else {
                        // Do some other stuff
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            this.props.meteorReady && this.state.initialRoute ?
            <Navigator
                ref={navigator => this.navigator = navigator}
                initialRoute={this.state.initialRoute}
                renderScene={(route, navigator) => { ... }}
            /> : (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true}/>
                </View>
            )
        )
    }
}
```

The `/user/events/isActive` method call should only be run if `Meteor.user()` is defined (which should mean the user is logged in). However, when I look at the server call:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    '/user/events/isActive': function () {
        console.log('userId:', this.userId);
        if (this.userId) {
            const member = Members.findOne({userId: this.userId});
            if (member) {
                return member.eventId;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

The first call of this method (after a DDP disconnect and reconnect) ends up with `this.userId` being equal to `null`.

Basically, if `Meteor.user()` is defined on the client, I expect `this.userId` to be defined on the server. However, it appears that the minimongo on the client is giving a false positive before they are actually logged in (when they disconnect and reconnect).

My question is: If `Meteor.user()` is defined on the client, can I safely assume that `this.userId` will be defined on the server? As of now, I would say I cannot, so is there any other way for me to reliably determine if the user is truly logged in from the client side?

Comment: What if you try [`Meteor.userId()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-userId) instead of `this.userId` in your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I have finally figured out what was going on.

The `container` sends new props to its child component any time a reactive computation is invalidated. Also, Meteor methods are asynchronous, and if they are not resolved on the server, the client will continue to try to get a response until a reconnect. However, the `props` that are passed into `setInitialRoute` are the `nextProps` from `componentWillReceiveProps`.

So, what was happening was that a call was being made right as the meteor server was disconnected, and the resolution of that call occurred after the reconnect. So the previous call of the meteor method was being evaluated, giving me a `null` for the `this.userId`.

To solve this, I just had to put a conditional within the callback of the meteor method to ensure that it was evaluated when the user is actually logged in (using the current props rather than the passed in `nextProps`):

```
Meteor.call('/user/events/isActive', (e, eventId) => {
    if (this.props.meteorReady) {...}
});
```

This prevents the result from that call of the method from being evaluated on the client, and solved my problem.